# Is $\mathbb{Z}[√13] $ a Unique factorization domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

I think it is not so as $12 $ can be written in two ways $12=2.6=(1+\sqrt{13})(-1+\sqrt{13})$. Are these two factorization unique upto irreducibles? Please help.

Comment: $6$ isn't irreducible!

Comment: $\left(\sqrt{13}-3\right)\left(\sqrt{13}+3\right)=2\cdot2$

Answer (score 6):

*Hint for the title question*: We have $${\displaystyle (1+{\sqrt {13}})^{2}=2(7+{\sqrt {13}})}.$$
Since $2$ is irreducible in ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} [{\sqrt {13}}]}$ but does not divide ${\displaystyle 1+{\sqrt {13}}}$, we see that ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} [{\sqrt {13}}]}$ is not a UFD.

Comment: (+1) I don't know if it is easier than I think to show that $2$ is irreducible, so I added an answer that shows this fact.

Answer (score 2):

**$\mathbf{2}$ is Irreducible in $\boldsymbol{\mathbb{Z}\!\left[\sqrt{13}\right]}$**

Suppose that
$$
\left(a+b\sqrt{13}\right)\left(c+d\sqrt{13}\right)=2\tag1
$$
where $2\nmid\left(a+b\sqrt{13}\right)$ and $2\nmid\left(c+d\sqrt{13}\right)$. Then
$$
ac+13bd=2\tag2
$$
and
$$
ad+bc=0\tag3
$$
If $2\mid a$, then since $2\nmid\left(a+b\sqrt{13}\right)$, we must have $2\nmid b$. Then $(2)$ says that $2\mid d$ and $(3)$ says that $2\mid c$. However, this means that $2\mid\left(c+d\sqrt{13}\right)$, which contradicts the hypotheses. Therefore, $2\nmid a$. Similarly, $2\nmid c$.

Multiplying $(2)$ by $ac$ and applying $(3)$ to eliminate $d$ gives
$$
a^2c^2-13b^2c^2=2ac\tag4
$$
and therefore,
$$
(ac-1)^2-1\equiv b^2c^2\pmod4\tag5
$$
However, since $a,c\equiv1\pmod2$, we must have $(ac-1)^2-1\equiv3\pmod4$. Since $3$ is not a quadratic residue mod $4$, $(5)$ can have no solutions.

Thus, $2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}\!\left[\sqrt{13}\right]$.

---

**$\boldsymbol{\mathbb{Z}\!\left[\sqrt{13}\right]}$ is not a UFD**
$$
\left(\sqrt{13}-3\right)\left(\sqrt{13}+3\right)=2\cdot2
$$

Comment: This is certainly useful (+1).

Comment: Dear robjohn: this is a nice answer. Alternatively, I think you can use the norm here. Precisely, if $N \colon \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}] \to \mathbb{Z}$ sends $a+b\sqrt{13}$ to $a^{2}-13b^{2}$, then it is not too hard to show that $N$ is multiplicative. If $u, v \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}]$ such that $2 = uv$, then applying $N$ gives $4 = N(u)N(v)$, so it suffices to show that we cannot have $N(u) = N(v) = 2$, i.e. $a^{2}-13b^{2} = 2$ has no integer solutions. But working mod $4$, this equation becomes $a^{2}-b^{2} = 2$, which is impossible since $0, 1$ are the only quadratic residues mod $4$.

Answer (score -2):

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}]$ is not even integrally closed (consider for instance $\displaystyle \frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}$), Hence it can't be a principal ideal domain. It also can't be a unique factorization domain because a Dedekind domain is a PID if and only if it is a UFD, but $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}]$ is not even integrally closed thus not Dedekind. At any rate: if you're not integrally closed then you're not a UFD.

Comment: "Hence it can't be a principal ideal domain and can't be thus be a unique factorization domain." Could you explain ?

Comment: Not being Euclidean is irrelevant for the purpose of determining whether or not it's a UFD (or a PID, which shares the same issue). Being integrally closed (in the filed of fraction) is, on the other hand, necessary for being a UFD.

Comment: Thanks for the info let me edit this!

Comment: @Gae.S. better now? TheSilverDoe: the integral closure must be a Dedekind domain and so if you're not integrally closed, you're not a Dedekind domain, hence not PID!

Comment: @CalicoJackRackham My question is about "why being not a PID implies that you are not an UFD ?" (hint : this is incorrect, consider $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ or $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]$)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ohhh you're right! I got that wrong! I think I got that right now...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Let me know if I got it right now...

Comment: @CalicoJackRackham Yes, but quite complicated ! The last sentence of your answer could be enough :)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe haha exactly!